# Fourier Sine Series issue: Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type

Tags: helper, continuous-fourier

Here is my code:

```
clearvars;
clc; 
close all;

%Define the domain: 
l=1;
%and consider, say, 4 periods
x=linspace(-4,4);
%Define the number of terms to consider
n_tot=50;
%Initialize the vectors containing each term of the series
FSS_term_x=zeros(n_tot,length(x));
%Loop to compute each term of the series up to n_tot
for n=1:n_tot
    %n-th term of the series for f(x)=x
    FSS_term_x(n,:)=((-2.*l.^2./n.pi).*cos(n.*pi)+2.*(l.^2)./(n.*pi).^2.*(cos(n.*pi)-1)).*sin(n.*pi.*x./l);
    %-2.*l./(n.*pi).*cos(n.*pi).*sin(n.*x.*pi/l);
end
%Add up all the terms of the series
FS_y=sum(FSS_term_x,1);
%Plot the series
figure
plot(x,FS_y)
```

and here is the error message:

```
Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.

Error in untitled3 (line 16)
    FSS_term_x(n,:)=((-2.*l.^2./n.pi).*cos(n.*pi)+2.*(l.^2)./(n.*pi).^2.*(cos(n.*pi)-1)).*sin(n.*pi.*x./l);
```

Does this error occur because the Fourier Sine Series I am trying to graph is piece-wise smooth?

Any feedback is appreciated!

Best,

RK

Answer (score 1):

You miss a multiplication (*) sign in the expression in your `for` loop. It regards the first bracketed term on the rhs: in your code it says `(-2.*l.^2./n.pi)` (*notice the `n.pi` at the end!*), while it should be `(-2.*l.^2./n.*pi)`.

So, the expression in the `for` loop should be:

```
FSS_term_x(n,:)=((-2.*l.^2./n.*pi).*cos(n.*pi)+2.*(l.^2)./(n.*pi).^2.*(cos(n.*pi)-1)).*sin(n.*pi.*x./l);
    %-2.*l./(n.*pi).*cos(n.*pi).*sin(n.*x.*pi/l);
```